# Colored Image unresponsive and gives an error

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-image

I am trying to read an image from the skimage.data. colored image appears but not responding . Also I am getting valurError. Here are my commands and errors.

```
>>> import skimage
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import scipy as sp
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> from skimage import data
>>> cat=data.chelsea()
>>> plt.imshow(cat,interpolation='nearest');
<matplotlib.image.AxesImage object at 0x0788BDF0>
>>> plt.show(cat)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    plt.show(cat)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 253, in show
    return _show(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 166, in __call__
    if block:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Can anyone help me to get through this error?

Comment: `plt.show()`, not `plt.show(cat)`

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.